# Testing whether an iterator points to the last item?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I have an stl iterator resulting from a std::find() and wish to test whether it is the last element.  One way to write this is as follows:

```
mine *match = someValue;
vector<mine *> Mine(someContent);
vector<mine *>::iterator itr = std::find(Mine.begin(), Mine.end(), match);

if (itr == --Mine.end()) {
  doSomething;
}
```

But it seems to me that decrementing the end() iterator is asking for trouble, such as if the vector has no elements, then it would be undefined.  Even if I know it will never be empty, it still seems ugly. I'm thinking that maybe rbegin() is the way to go, but am not certain as to best way to compare the forward iterator with a reverse iterator.

Comment: Something does seem ugly here.  I suggest it's not how you determine if `itr` is pointing to the last element, however.  What's ugly is that you need to know if `itr` is pointing to the last element.

Comment: @John: You may be right. Maybe it would make more sense to check using: `if (Mine.Length() != 0 && &Mine[Mine.Length()-1] == itr)`, or something close to that.

Comment: Hmm, my answer is ugly, too. It should have been GMan's first suggestion: `if (&Mine.back() == itr)`.

Comment: @Steven:  I'd wager if we knew the larger context of this code, we could figure out what's really wrong and fix it.  I have a theory.  If the code resists being written, it's because it knows it's wrong.

Comment: @John: Again, you may be right. All too often, something is awkward because it's fighting against the more natural way of doing things.

Comment: If what you get isn't the `.end()` of the vector, it means the vector has at least one element, so `-- .end()` should be defined.

Comment: @John @Steven: Yes, this code is awkward, I am working around a bug in code outside my control provided by a 3rd party.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Do this:

```
// defined in boost/utility.hpp, by the way
template <typename Iter>
Iter next(Iter iter)
{
    return ++iter;
}

// first check we aren't going to kill ourselves
// then check if the iterator after itr is the end
if ((itr != Mine.end()) && (next(itr) == Mine.end()))
{
    // points at the last element
}
```

That is all. Never gives you undefined behavior, works on all iterators, good day.

Wrap it up for fun:

```
template <typename Iter, typename Cont>
bool is_last(Iter iter, const Cont& cont)
{
    return (iter != cont.end()) && (next(iter) == cont.end())
}
```

Giving:

```
if (is_last(itr, Mine))
```

---

If you're allergic to utility functions/nice looking code, do:

```
if ((itr != Mine.end()) && (itr + 1 == Mine.end()))
```

But you can't do it on non-random-access iterators. This one works with bidirectional iterators:

```
if ((itr != Mine.end()) && (itr == --Mine.end()))
```

And is safe since `end() > itr` by the first check.

Comment: Concerning reverse iterators: `Mine.rbegin().base() == Mine.end();`. Reverse iterators store an iterator to the next element from the one you get when it is dereferenced. You'd still need to increment it first.

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment to the OP, I think the whole idea of needing to know if `itr` points to the last element is a code smell.  Something just isn't right with that.  However, if you really need to do this, this is how I'd do it.

Comment: The first one is the closest to being correct, except that it unnecessarily dereferences only to reference again. Also, doesn't `back()` throw if the vector is empty?

Comment: @Uncle: Ah, I forgot. :( No point really, then. @Steven: `&itr` gets the address of the iterator. `*itr` returns a reference to the element. `&(*itr)` is the address of the reference of the element (address of the element). And no, you'll just get undefined behavior, which is why I give the disclaimer at the bottom. OP should either `assert` it's not the end/empty or explicitly check it, for safety.

Comment: @Steven: OP says the vector will never be empty. An `assert` might do good here. And no, `&*it` does make sense for iterators, since the `*` operator is overloaded.

Comment: `back` does `*--a.end()` (23.1.1, table 68) which is exactly what OP suggested plus an unsafe dereference.

Comment: @GMan: The problem is that, if `itr` is `Mine.end()`, you're not guaranteed that it's safe to dereference. For vectors, it happens to work, but for linked lists, maps and other types, it may or may not, depending on whether there's a sentinel node or null pointer. However, `itr` already casts to an element pointer, so just leave it be.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: You can decrement a forward_iterator?

Comment: @Steven: Again, that's why I give the disclaimer at the bottom.

Comment: @Steven: That's what the standard says. `back` is optional and it doesn't make sense in a forward sequence anyway.

Comment: btw, shouldn't you give a temporary value, as to not tamper with the original value? `T next(const &T x){ return x+1; }`

Comment: -1 for still suggesting UB (`back` on an empty vector is illegal) and convolution (reverse iterators can't be justified).

Comment: @Michael: No need, as x is being passed by value, anyhow.

Comment: I'm moving the disclaimer to the top since people are apparently blind. No, I'll just give the best answer, forget options. @Michael: The copy is made in the parameter.

Comment: @Michael: Ditto. My C++ is obviously rusty, which is how I wound up half-wrong about `&*`. The half I wasn't wrong about is that it's not something you should do on an iterator that equals `end()`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I'm not sure what you're talking about when you say reverse iterators cannot be justified. When you -1'd my answer basically said "there's no point in doing anything with a reverse iterator".

Comment: @GMan: The concept of a reverse iterator is simply extraneous to solving the problem. Also, using `std::advance` doesn't require Boost. The -1 is more about UB; now that you've added a check against it I'll undownvote…

Comment: @Potato: But the OP mentioned reverse iterators in his question, I was addressing that by saying "there's no point". `std::advance` is mutating, `next` is not and reads better.

Comment: Oops, thanks, I forgot that about `advance`. Not that it's worth discussing, but you did include `rbegin` in a completely unironic suggestion.

Comment: @GMan You can't do `itr + 1` if it's not random access can you?

Comment: @Mark: Correct, it was sort of a trade-off thing.

Comment: The call `--Mine.end()` is not guaranteed to compile or work as expected. For example, pointers are valid iterators. Remember, `--x` doesn't mean `x-1`; it means `x=x-1`. That's why you have to create a variable and call the decrement operator on that (either directly with `--` or using `std::advance`).

Comment: std::next available in C++11

Comment: Missing semicolon after `return (iter != cont.end()) && (next(iter) == cont.end())`

Answer (score 19):

Yes, it's unsafe to decrement (or increment) `end` if the vector may be empty. It's even somewhat unsafe to do the same with a pointer, although you'll probably get away with it.

To be really safe, use subtraction and values known to be safe and valid:

```
if ( Mine.end() - itr == 1 )
```

For compatibility with all forward iterators (such as in `slist`, as opposed to random-access iterators of `vector` and `deque`), use

```
if ( std::distance( itr, Mine.end() ) == 1 )
```

or if you are concerned with performance but have bidirectional iterators (incl. any C++03 container)

```
if ( itr != Mine.end() && itr == -- Mine.end() )
```

or the truly anal case of only forward iterators and O(1) time,

```
if ( itr != Mine.end() && ++ container::iterator( itr ) == Mine.end() )
```

or if you are hellbent on cleverness to avoid naming the iterator class,

```
if ( itr != Mine.end() && ++ ( Mine.begin() = itr ) == Mine.end() )
```

Comment: This should work, and while the pointer arithmetic isn't all that clear, at least this avoids potentially trying to dereference a null pointer.

Comment: You changed your answer to make it worse: now it only works with vectors.

Comment: @Steven: It was wrong before. The question only involves vectors. The edit didn't change its compatibility anyway, as I only eliminated a (universal) operation.

Comment: I can't imagine that calculating `Mine.end() - itr` could be efficient on a linked list, even if it's legal.

Comment: @Steven: I didn't change that part. Anyway, I updated with compatibility options.

Comment: Since you're relying on bidirectional iterators for `(++iter)--`, you can assume `end()` can `--` too, and since you passed `&&` you know `itr < end`, so can just do `... && iter == --Mine.end()`.

Comment: @Gman: yeah, thanks… I ended up with this oddity by trying to avoid naming the iterator class while working with standard tools… hmm

Comment: @Potato: That last one is pretty clever, nice.

Answer (score 5):

Why do you need to do special behavior only if the item is the last one?

What about this. The plan is just to compare the address of the iterator's item with the address of the last item in the container, with a check to make sure the item is actually not already the end (making the `back` call safe):

```
if (itr != Mine.end() && &*itr == &Mine.back()) {
  doSomething;
}
```

Comment: This is *almost* right, in that it'll fail if `Mine.length()` is 0.

Comment: @Steven How can `Mine.length()` be 0 if it found a valid iterator in the container that's not end? By definition that iterator points to an item and thus `length` can't be 0. Or do I miss something obvious?

Comment: Well, the `find` method can return `Mine.end()` if nothing was found.

Comment: @Steven And the first part of my check where I test that find didn't return `end` catches that.

Comment: You're correct. If you edit your answer, I'll be able to upvote it.

Answer (score 5):

You would first need a way to [**determine if an iterator is a reverse one**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22360697/2567683), which was [ingeniously shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22361499/2567683) :

```
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Iter>
struct is_reverse_iterator : std::false_type { };

template<typename Iter>
struct is_reverse_iterator<std::reverse_iterator<Iter>>
: std::integral_constant<bool, !is_reverse_iterator<Iter>::value>
{ };
```

Then you could have two flavors for performing the test

```
template<bool isRev> // for normal iterators
struct is_last_it
{
    template<typename It, typename Cont>
    static bool apply(It it, Cont const &cont)
    { // you need to test with .end()
        return it != cont.end() && ++it == cont.end();
    }
};

template<> // for reverse iterators
struct is_last_it<true>
{
    template<typename It, typename Cont>
    static bool apply(It it, Cont const &cont)
    { // you need to test with .rend()
        return it != cont.rend() && ++it == cont.rend();
    }
};
```

And a single interface function

```
template<typename It, typename Cont>
bool is_last_iterator(It it, Cont const &cont)
{
    return is_last_it<is_reverse_iterator<It>::value>::apply(it, cont);
};
```

Then for every type of iterator (reverse / straight) you can use the interface function

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);

    auto it (v.begin()),  ite(v.end());   // normal iterators
    auto rit(v.rbegin()), rite(v.rend()); // reverse iterators

    std::cout << is_last_iterator(it, v) << std::endl;
    std::cout << is_last_iterator(ite, v) << std::endl;
    std::cout << is_last_iterator(rit, v) << std::endl;
    std::cout << is_last_iterator(rite, v) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Note that some implementation (apart from `std::begin()` and `std::end()` which are common enough, also include `std::rbegin()` and `std::rend()`. When possible use this set of functions instead of member `.begin()` etc.

Comment: A beautiful answer from the language perspective, but I wonder about including all this header everywhere just for a simple check (compilation time, learning curve, etc.) +1 anyway.

Answer (score 3):

If you do:

```
if(itr != Mine.end() && itr == --Mine.end())
```

It should be fine. Because if itr is not at the end then there must be at least 1 element in the container and so end must yield a value result when decremented.

But if you still don't like that, there are lots of ways to do something equivalent, as all the other answers show.

Here's another alternative:

```
if(itr != Mine.end() && std::distance(Mine.begin(), itr) == Mine.size()-1)
```

Comment: In the second solution if the container is list-like, it'll have to walk the whole list to determine the distance.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another potential solution:

```
template<class Iterator, class Container> bool is_last(Iterator it, const Container& cont)
{
    // REQUIREMENTS:
    // the iterator must be a valid iterator for `cont`
    if( it == cont.end() )
        return false;   // or throw if you prefer
    return (++it) == cont.end();
}
```

Comment: +1, didn't see your answer, sorry for stepping on your toes. We hive-minded the function signature, though, high-five.

Comment: I don't believe all control paths return a value... there should be `return false;` as the last line of the function, right?

Comment: @John You need a tail return false in your template function.

Comment: @GMan:  We sure did.  At least I can be a little more sure I got the signature right! :)

Comment: The final three lines could just be `return it == cont.end();`

Comment: @Mark B:  I wrote it more verbose to be a little clearer as to intent, but you're probably right -- that wasn't necessary.  Changed code.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to make this answer as simple and versatile as possible:

```
if( itr!=Mine.end() && itr== --Mine.end())
```

If the iterator is not bi-directional,

```
if( itr!=Min.end() && ++decltype(itr)(itr)==Mine.end())
```

The second create a temporal copy of itr and increment it to test against the end iterator.

In both cases, the first test avoid empty containers to trigger an undefined situation.

Answer (score 1):

A better way would be to copy the iterator and then increment it. You can then test the incremented version against `end()`. If you're careful, you can use a post-increment to avoid the need to formally copy it.

```
  if (++vector<mine*>::iterator(itr) == Mine.end())
```

If itr could already be at the end:

```
  if (itr == Mine.end() || ++vector<mine*>::iterator(itr) == Mine.end())
```

Or, based on GMan's answer but a bit safer:

```
  if (Mine.Length() == 0 || itr == Mine.End() || &*itr == &Mine.back())
```

I just fixed the last one again, as I was wrong about `&*`.

Comment: @GMan: If the goal is to determine whether the iterator points to the last valid element, this code will work consistently. If there is any risk of it already pointing past that last valid element, you can change the predicate to first test whether `itr == Mine.end()`, with an OR.

Comment: @Steven: You mean "better" as "works with forward iterators" then?

Comment: @GMan: I mean better in that it works correctly for any container.

Comment: -1 for convolution, no additional safety, and not appearing to work. What's the point of comparing the original, non-incremented value to `end`?

Comment: @Potatoswatter: You're right: I just fixed it to pre-increment the copied iterator instead of post-incrementing. Thanks.

Comment: Rescinded, although I prefer my third option.

Comment: Your third option decrements end, so I can't favor it.

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially the same problem as deleting a node from a singly-linked list.  You have to have two iterators, one that follows one node behind the other, so when the "forward" iterator gets to the node you want to delete (or whatever operation; in your case the desired node would be the end), the "following" iterator is pointing to the node before (in your case, this would be the final node).

Comment: Yes, that's kind of what I was incoherently alluding to when I said that "If you're careful, you can use a post-increment to avoid the need to formally copy it."  So long as you keep the previous value of the iterator, you can pre-increment the current value and have that available even as you operate on the previous value. It's a little bit tricky to set up correctly, though.