# Linker errors using static function template members of a class

Tags: c++, templates, vector, compiler-errors, cmake

I don't understand why it's not compiling correctly, the linker reports missing symbols:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "bool swinadventure::Utils::is_last<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >, std::vector > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >, std::vector > const&)", referenced from:
      swinadventure::Inventory::get_item_list(std::string, std::string) in Inventory.cpp.o

Because eariler in the process I also see this error: `/usr/bin/ranlib: file: liblibswinadventure.a(Utils.cpp.o) has no symbols` I assume that it's not compiling the utils file correctly for some reason.

For reference, I'm using CMake on a Mac OS X 10.7 system with most homebrew tools installed and linked.

**Utils.h**

```
#ifndef UTILS_H_
#define UTILS_H_

#include <vector>

namespace swinadventure {

/**
 * Static class for various utilities and helper functions
 */
class Utils {
public:
    template <typename Iter>
    static Iter next_iterator(Iter iter);
    template <typename Iter, typename Cont>
    static bool is_last(Iter iter, const Cont& cont);
};

} /* namespace swinadventure */
#endif /* UTILS_H_ */
```

**Utils.cpp**

```
#include "Utils.h"

namespace swinadventure {

/**
 * Returns the next iterator
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516196/testing-whether-an-iterator-points-to-the-last-item
 * @param iter
 * @return
 */
template <typename Iter>
Iter Utils::next_iterator(Iter iter) {
    return ++iter;
}

/**
 * Checks if the iterator is the last of the vector array
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516196/testing-whether-an-iterator-points-to-the-last-item
 * @param iter  iterator
 * @param cont  vector array
 * @return
 */
template <typename Iter, typename Cont>
bool Utils::is_last(Iter iter, const Cont& cont)
{
    return (iter != cont.end()) && (next_iterator(iter) == cont.end());
}

} /* namespace swinadventure */
```

Comment: Duplicate of so many questions with this problem.

Comment: such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639797/template-issue-causes-linker-error-c?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score 1):

**Move your template function definitions to the header.**

The linker is telling you that while compiling `Inventory.cpp`, a special instantiation of `Utils::is_last` was needed, but the definition wasn't available to create it.

And while compiling `Utils.cpp`, the definition of `Utils::is_last` was available, but that instantiation wasn't needed.

So neither source file was able to create that function while compiling.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a template, the variables inside the <> become stand-ins for the type passed, and as such these variables are used in the same way as classes and only need to be declared once.  Thus `template <typename Iter, typename Cont>` can should be treated as if it were a class definition, and moved outside of the `class Utils {` definition.  The other instances of `template` should be removed as well, especially before the `Utils::func()` definitions.  As it stands now, you're basically telling it "Create a class named Iter. Create a class named Iter. Create a class named Iter, etc." As soon as it encounters a variable of the type 'Iter', it doesn't know which one it should use.  This site should help with templates, and is worth the look:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/templates.html