# Determine if a (c++) iterator is reverse

Tags: c++, templates

I want a mechanism to determine in compile time whether an iterator is reverse or not.

[**Iterator traits**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/iterator_traits/) can only help with the **category** of an iterator type and what I need is something in the lines of:

```
template<typename IterType>
struct IsReverseIterator
{
    enum { Yes = /* Implementation of the mechanism */ };
}
```

**I have a solution, that has a small drawback** though, the container type has to be provided as well :

```
typedef char     TrueT;
typedef struct { TrueT _[2]; } FalseT;

template<typename Cont> TrueT  IsReverseIterator(typename Cont::const_reverse_iterator);    
template<typename Cont> FalseT IsReverseIterator(...);
```

It uses SFINAE obviously and can be utilized like so :

```
std::vector<int> v;

std::cout << (sizeof(IsReverseIterator<std::vector<int>>(v.begin())) ==  sizeof(TrueT)) << std::endl;
std::cout << (sizeof(IsReverseIterator<std::vector<int>>(v.rbegin())) ==  sizeof(TrueT)) << std::endl;
```

**Any ideas?**

**EDIT**

To explain what I'm searching for, take for example the following code

```
template<typename Cont, typename It>
bool points_to_last_element(Cont const &container, It iter)
{
    return iter == container.rend(); 
    // here I would like to dispatch to 2 implementations
    // one for reverse iterators and one for forward where this would happen
    // return iter == container.end();
}
```

It is a dummy example, please don't get caught on the fact that the code I have already handles it or that I could have two overloads, one taking `Cont::reverse_iterator` and one taking `Cont::iterator`. I don't/can't change that design, I'm just trying a more elegant way (if there's any) to handle it internally. Again I repeat that was a dummy example.

Comment: What about `reverse_iterator`? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/reverse_iterator/

Comment: @GIJoe he knows *what* one is; he wants to know, given an iterator, *whether* one is. (I may have misunderstood your comment though.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I guess that's my point.. he already knows he needs a reverse_iterator. I don't see a possibility where anything else would be accepted if you are passing a reverse_iterator to begin with

Comment: Why do you care?  Can you just check `.base()` (and see if it returns an iterator)?  What do you mean by 'is a reverse iterator' exactly?  I can write a class that is one for all intents, but is not returned by `std::reverse_iterator`.  How implementation defined is ok?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Iter>
struct is_reverse_iterator : std::false_type { };

template<typename Iter>
struct is_reverse_iterator<std::reverse_iterator<Iter>>
: std::integral_constant<bool, !is_reverse_iterator<Iter>::value>
{ };
```

You could also specialize the trait for any user-defined iterators that are reverse iterators.

Comment: That's so perfect it makes me wonder why it's not in the standard library. Thnx man I'm officially glad I asked this after all.

Comment: Because noone needs it, your function should be `points_to_last_element(Cont const &container, It iter, It end)` and check `iter == end`, it shouldn't matter whether it's a reverse iterator or not

Comment: I suppose if I had the end, there would be no need at all. How one acquires the `end` iterator from the caller function for iterator `It iter` and container `Cont cont`? Is it `begin()` or `rbegin()` (I'm posting this as a comment to not clutter the question)

Comment: How did you obtain `iter`? Wherever that comes from is the place where you know how to obtain the past-the-end iterator

Comment: That's (was - it's not any more) the problem I can't add code there, I can only be the user/client of that code

Comment: Note: 'typedef std::reverse_iterator<std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator> reverse_reverse;'

Comment: @DieterLücking, yeah, I considered that, and couldn't be bothered solving it :-) You need to recurse - fixed now.

Comment: Why didn't you just inherit from `std::true_type` in the specialization?

Comment: @0x499602D2, see the two comments above yours, it handles reverse-reverse-iterators, which are not reverse iterators.

Answer (score 0):

A simple method. It is easy to use and can determine if something is a reverse iterator or not, and can differentiate between const reverse iterators if needed.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename Container, typename T>
using IsRegRevIter = std::is_same<T,typename Container::reverse_iterator>;

template<typename Container, typename T>
using IsConstRevIter = std::is_same<T,typename Container::const_reverse_iterator>;

template<typename Container, typename T>
struct IsRevIter
{
     const static bool value = IsRegRevIter<Container,T>::value
          || IsConstRevIter<Container,T>::value;
};

int main()
{
     using Container = std::list<int>;
     Container myList = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

     auto RI = myList.rbegin();
     auto I = myList.begin();

     std::cout << std::endl << std::boolalpha << IsRevIter<Container,decltype(RI)>::value; //true
     std::cout << std::endl << std::boolalpha << IsRegRevIter<Container,decltype(RI)>::value; //true
     std::cout << std::endl << std::boolalpha << IsConstRevIter<Container,decltype(RI)>::value; //false (it is not const).
     std::cout << std::endl << std::boolalpha << IsRevIter<Container,decltype(I)>::value; //false

return 0;

}
```

> output: 
> false 
> true 
> false 
> false