# is iterator end() of the container

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Is there a way to check that iterator (passed to function as parameter "last") is equal to end() in case I haven't the container itself?

```
template<typename ForwardIterator>
void MyFunc(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last) {
...
}
```

Comment: `MyFunc` shouldn't need to know if `last` is the end of any given container or not, if it does then you should probably rethink its design.

Comment: So you're asking if you can compare to a value which you don't have?

Comment: No, the OP is asking whether the iterator can itself determine if it is equal to a value the OP doesn't have.

Comment: The code above can't even establish if the iterator is to a container ! Consider a stream iterator from an `std::ifstream`.

Comment: Generally, no. Iterators can be many things. Given `int arr[7];`, then `arr` and `arr+7` are valid iterators.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK - no. If you don't have the container, you can't get the ::end() iterator, thus you can't do the comparison. Why not pass the container as reference?

Check out:
[Testing whether an iterator points to the last item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516196/testing-whether-an-iterator-points-to-the-last-item)

Comment: trying to write an algorithm in stl-style which are getting first and last iterators of the sequence

Comment: In which case you should use last as the end of the sequence

Comment: Last is not supposed to be the end of the sequence. It is supposed to be the iterator pointing to the last element in range you wish to get processed by algorithm. In other words - if you want to pass an iterator to the end, then do it, but don't force it.

Comment: In stl descriptions, I see typically: "....the range [first, last) ...." , so that means that "last" element is not included into algorithm logic?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, `MyFunc` should consider the range including `first` and *excluding* `last` just as the standard algorithms do, too.

Which is done in the standard library for the exact reason (or problem) that you are stating. Typical calls to algorithm functions that take e.g. an entire container look like `algoname(foo.begin(), foo.end());` where `foo.end()` is an iterator that points to an invalid element *after the last valid one*.
The algorithm would thus need to somehow know whether it can dereference any given iterator (or, at the very least, the one given in `last`).

On the other hand, the problem is entirely avoided by defining that `last` is exclusive. So, for example iterating over the elements can be done in terms of `for(... it != last)`, and this same code will work for *any* and *every* value of `last`, both ones that refer to valid objects, and the one returned by `end()`. The only thing the implementation needs to make sure is that `first <= last`, and nothing can go wrong.

Comment: acutally I'm writing a learning task to implement classic sort algorithms, e.g. for bubble sort:
template<typename BidirectionalIterator>
void BubbleSort(BidirectionalIterator first, BidirectionalIterator last) {
    while( first != --last )
        for(BidirectionalIterator iter2 = first; iter2 != last ; ++iter2)
            if (*iter2 > *(iter2 + 1) )
                std::swap(*iter2, *(iter2 + 1));         does it look ok in terms of iterating?

Comment: Since you decrement `last` you need to be sure that `first != last` (`first == last` is nonsensical for sorting, but nevertheless legal). Also, you need `last > first` for that loop. So alltogether a `>=` check is missing. While `first > last` doesn't make sense and isn't legal according to your API contract (given the names "first" and "last"), doing it wrong shouldn't cause your code to be trapped in an infinite loop.

Comment: so I can't use last > first because supposed that iterators are bidirectional, not a randomaccess

Comment: That's unluckily true, so equality is the best you can use in that case to guard against empty ranges (you can't protect yourself against reversed ranges).

Comment: Yeah, I see, the only issue can be safe is first== last initially. I'll add the condition. Thank you